# Volume forms under diffeomorphisms

Tags: differential-geometry

I have an exercise and I have no idea how to do it:

Let be $U$ and $V$ open sets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f:U\rightarrow V$ an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism, then

$$f^{*}(\operatorname{vol}_{V}) = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij}(x))} \operatorname{vol}_{U}$$

Where $\operatorname{vol}_{V}$ and $\operatorname{vol}_{U}$ are the volume forms of $U$ and $V$  $f^{*}$ the pullback of $f$, and $g_{ij}(x)=D_xf(e_i)\cdot D_xf(e_j)$

Comment: What's $g_{ij}$?